# Is there a way of tracking whats still pointing to a object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I'v been trying to track down why a block of memory that isn't released. I can see it alloc but when I leave the view and return it's reallocated. It's allocating a nib then using the view.

**Is there a way of tracking whats still pointing to the object?**

[image: Instruments]

```
    TPDatePickerKeyboardView *keyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TPDatePickerKeyboardView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    keyboard.delegate = self;
    keyboard.associatedControl = self;
    self.datePickerKeyboard = keyboard;

    self.inputView = keyboard;
```

**I've found the Object but it's part of UIKit?**

[image: Object Summary]
[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a way to see that. But assuming self.datePickerKeyboard and self.inputView retain the object, you should call [keyboard release] after `self.inputView = keyboard;` (apologies if I am stating the obvious)

Comment: Are you using ARC? How is the property for datPickerKeyboard defined?

Comment: I'm using arc and I've got a weak pointer to the keyboard view

Comment: If you display the object summary in Instruments and drill down through "categories" to an actual object, it should show the retain/release history.  Does that give any clues to what may still be holding it?

Comment: Since it seems related to nib loading, the only (far-fetched) idea I can think of at the moment is to make sure any IBOutlets you have connected to nib elements that are **not top-level objects** are declared weak.

Answer (score 0):

In viewWillDisappear try adding self. datePickerKeyboard.delegate = nil; and see if that takes care of it.